# What is a robust floating point operation for less < or greater > comparisons?

Tags: r, precision, floating-accuracy

What is a robust and concise way to make less `<`and greater `>` comparisons that are robust to [floating-point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/4464562), i.e., operations that are robust to small differences that could stem from floating-point inaccuracy issues?

In other terms: For `==` we have [`all.equal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/4464562), but what do we have for `<` and `>`?

### Tidyverse example with tibble

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~ x, 0.1 + 0.2) %>%
  mutate(
    test = x > 0.3
  )
```

results in

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      x test 
  <dbl> <lgl>
1   0.3 TRUE
```

whereas I would expect `FALSE` instead of `TRUE` (since 0.3 > 0.3 mathematically is false).

Comment: Could you clarify what you are hoping to get? Do you want a version of `>` that ignores small differences that could plausibly be floating point accuracy issues? I assume you want your example to produce `FALSE`, not `TRUE`...

Comment: Thank you, I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate because [this answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309050/190277) shows how to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Translating from the linked answer for `>=`, the answer to my question would be a check like: `0.1 + 0.2 > 0.3 & !all.equal(0.1 + 0.2, 0.3)`